# ReferenceError: tasks is not defined Warning: Task "default" not found. Use

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I get the following error when running grunt:

Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
ReferenceError: tasks is not defined
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

My gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  [
    'grunt-cafe-mocha',
    'grunt-contrib-jshint',
    'grunt-exec',
  ].forEach(function(task){
    grunt.loadNpmTasks(tasks);
  });

  // configure plugins
  grunt.initConfig({
    cafemocha: {
      all: {src: 'qa/tests-*.js', options: {ui: 'tdd'}, }
    },
    jshint: {
      app: ['app.js', 'public/js/**/*.js',
        'lib/**/*.js'],
      qa: ['gruntfile.js', 'public/qa/**/*.js', 'qa/**/*.js'],
    },
    exec: {
      linechecker:
        {cmd: 'linechecker http://localhost:3000'}
    }
  });

  // register tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['cafemocha', 'jshint', 'exec']);
};
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your npmLoadTasks(tasks) should be npmLoadTasks(task)